# Send a POST request, receive a PDF in return and save it to the filesystem in NativeScript

Tags: nativescript-vue

I want to send a POST request containing JSON to a server for processing. The server will then return a PDF which I want to receive, save to the filesystem and display using [nativescript-pdf-view](https://github.com/madmas/nativescript-pdf-view). However, [`File.writeSync()`](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_file_system_.file#writesync) [will not accept the ArrayBuffer](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/4486) that I get from the server response. Instead, it expects the native variants NSData (iOS) and ByteArray (Android). How can I convert the ArrayBuffer to the native byte arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Sending the POST request

As explained by the official documentation, a POST request can be sent using the [`getBinary()`](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/modules/_http_#getbinary) function:

```js
import { getBinary } from 'tns-core-modules/http'

getBinary({
  url: 'https://example.com/foo/bar/generate-pdf',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
  content: JSON.stringify(someObject),
})
```

Here, `someObject` is the object you want to convert to JSON and send to the server.

## Receiving, converting and saving the file / PDF

The response will contain the PDF or any other file as an [ArrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer). As mentioned in the question, the [`File.writeSync()`](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_file_system_.file#writesync) method expects NSData (iOS) and ByteArray (Android). So, we need to get a file handler, convert our file and save it to the filesystem.

```js
import { getBinary } from 'tns-core-modules/http'
import { isAndroid } from 'tns-core-modules/platform'
import { File, knownFolders, path } from 'tns-core-modules/file-system'

getBinary({
  url: 'https://example.com/foo/bar/generate-pdf',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
  content: JSON.stringify(someObject),
}).then((buffer) => {

  // Get file handler
  const documentsFolder = knownFolders.documents()
  const destination = path.join(documentsFolder.path, 'result.pdf')
  const file = File.fromPath(destination)

  // Convert buffer to byte array
  let byteArray
  if (isAndroid) {
    byteArray = Array.create('byte', buffer.byteLength)
    for (let i = 0; i < buffer.length; i++) {
      byteArray[i] = new java.lang.Byte(buffer[i])
    }
  } else {
    byteArray = NSData.dataWithBytesLength(buffer, buffer.byteLength)
  }

  // Save file
  file.writeSync(byteArray, (error) => {
    console.log(error)
  });
})
```

Why the [`File.writeSync()`](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_file_system_.file#writesync) method doesn't convert this automatically is a miracle to me. Maybe someone else can explain!

## Displaying the PDF

To display the PDF, you can use [nativescript-pdf-view](https://github.com/madmas/nativescript-pdf-view). Just use the filehandler to get the path `file.path` or the `destination` variable and pass it to the `src` property of the PDFView component. This might look like this:

```html
<template>
  <Page>
    <ActionBar title="PDF" />
    <GridLayout rows="*" columns="*">
      <PDFView :src="path" row="0" col="0" />
    </GridLayout>
  </Page>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
export default {
  name: 'PdfViewer',
  props: {
    path: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Make sure to install the plugin, of course and introduce the element to Vue.js, first:

```js
// main.ts

Vue.registerElement('PDFView', () => require('nativescript-pdf-view').PDFView)
```